# C++ - Accessing char* with &String[0] on class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, c-strings

I was just experimenting and making my own string class. (Mainly because there is some stuff I wanted to build in custom methods like "toBase64" etc. Anyways, I was wondering how you could access the private member of char* when you use &String[0].

I thought you could use operator-overloading but I currently only have it as String[0] returns the char*. (I know & is the pointer operator).

String.h

```
namespace CoffeeBeans
{
    class _declspec(dllexport) Coffee_String
    {
        char* String;
        int StringLength;

    public:
        Coffee_String();
        Coffee_String(LPCSTR CString);

        LPSTR operator[](int);

        ~Coffee_String();
    };
}
```

String.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "String.h"
#include <Windows.h>

CoffeeBeans::Coffee_String::Coffee_String() {
    this->String = nullptr;
    this->StringLength = 0;
}

CoffeeBeans::Coffee_String::~Coffee_String() {

    if (String != nullptr) {
        delete[] this->String;
        this->String = nullptr;
        this->StringLength = 0;
    }
}

CoffeeBeans::Coffee_String::Coffee_String(LPCSTR CString) {

    int StringLength = strlen(CString) + 1;

    this->String = new char[StringLength]();
    this->StringLength = StringLength - 1;
    memcpy_s(this->String, StringLength, CString, StringLength);
}

LPSTR CoffeeBeans::Coffee_String::operator[](int)
{
    return this->String;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
    case WM_CREATE:{
        CoffeeBeans::Coffee_String String("Test");

        //I want to be able to do
        //strcpy_s(&String[0], 3, "hi"); //Copy "hi" into the private variable char*String.
        //I know this isn't a practical use, I wanted quick example (I would really pass it to recv (WinSock2))

        MessageBeep(0);

    break;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: All those `this->`s are just noise. Get rid of them. In the destructor you don't need to test whether `String` is NULL; `delete` handles that just fine. And in the destructor there's no point in setting `String` to NULL and `StringLength` to 0; the object is going away, and nobody can see those values.

Comment: @PeteBecker alright I will delete that from my destructor, and I just was taught from my book that using this-> was a good habit because It knows you are referring to that object, etc.

Comment: @0x499602D2 My problem is I want to access the char* string (private member) from just using &String[0]. Unless I am miss interpreting how how std::string accesses the underlying string (which I very well could be) that way I can pass it into functions that pass back information. Like recv (Winsocks2)

Comment: "*I just was taught from my book that using `this->` was a good habit*" - then you need a new book!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `operator[]` is returning the wrong value.  In order for `&String[index]` to access the correct memory address, `operator[]` needs to return a reference to the character at the specified index, not return the string pointer itself, as you are currently doing.

If you look at the actual declaration of `std::string::operator[]`, you will see that it returns a `std::string::reference` (aka `char &`) or `std::string::const_reference` (aka `const char &`) (depending on whether it is being called on a non-const or const `std::string` object).

Try something more like this:

String.h

```
namespace CoffeeBeans
{
    class _declspec(dllexport) Coffee_String
    {
        char* String;
        int StringLength;

    public:
        Coffee_String();
        Coffee_String(const Coffee_String &src);
        Coffee_String(const char *src);
        ~Coffee_String();

        char& operator[](int index);
        const char& operator[](int index) const;

        Coffee_String& operator=(const Coffee_String &rhs);
    };
};
```

String.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "String.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring> 

CoffeeBeans::Coffee_String::Coffee_String() {
    String = nullptr;
    StringLength = 0;
}

CoffeeBeans::Coffee_String::Coffee_String(const CoffeeBeans::Coffee_String &src) {
    StringLength = src.StringLength;
    String = new char[StringLength+1];
    std::copy(src.String, src.String+StringLength, String);
    String[StringLength] = 0;
}

CoffeeBeans::Coffee_String::Coffee_String(const char *src) {
    StringLength = std::strlen(str);
    String = new char[StringLength+1];
    std::copy(src, src+StringLength, String);
    String[StringLength] = 0;
}

CoffeeBeans::Coffee_String::~Coffee_String() {
    delete[] String;
    String = nullptr;
    StringLength = 0;
}

char& CoffeeBeans::Coffee_String::operator[](int index)
{
    return String[index];
}

const char& CoffeeBeans::Coffee_String::operator[](int index) const
{
    return String[index];
}

CoffeeBeans::Coffee_String& CoffeeBeans::Coffee_String::operator=(const CoffeeBeans::Coffee_String &rhs);
{
    Coffee_String temp(rhs);
    std::swap(String, temp.String);
    std::swap(StringLength, temp.String);
    return *this;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
case WM_CREATE: {
    CoffeeBeans::Coffee_String String("Test");

    strcpy_s(&String[0], 3, "hi"); //Copy "hi" into the private variable char *String...
    // note that the content of String will become "hi\0t\0", not "hi\0"
    // and StringLength will still be 4...

    MessageBeep(0);

    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it